# Some bibliography extend past the end of line, how can I prevent this?

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I know that a lot of similar questions have been asked, but I can't find a solution to my problem ..

What I'm currently trying to do, is simply to get my bibliography done.
But one specific source, a book, goes past end of line, and I can't find a way to prevent this.

Here's a screenshot of that specific source.

[image: Screenshot of my problem, the title of the book that I cite is way longer than the line length]

Here's how I wrote it in my .bib file :

```
@book{Guzman:2018,

title = "Handbook of diseases of banana, abacá and enset",

author = "Guzman, M and Pérez-Vincente, L and Carlier, J",

year = 2018,

publisher = "Jones DR"

}
```

The problem seems to be that the title is put in a hbox because of, I guess, an /underline.

Does any of you know how could I make sure that this citation stays in it's supposed place ?

Thank you for your attention,
Have a nice day !

SOLVED :

I was using the ulem package, and simply had to add normaled to it like this :

```
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
```

Thanks for the really fast answers !

Comment: Which bibliography style are you using?

Comment: are you using the ulem package?

Comment: @DaiBowen \usepackage[natbib=true,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex} (I'm still pretty new to LaTeX so I hope you're talking about this style ?)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, I use the ulem package for the \underLine which I use in my text a few times.

Comment: @Cyaneis You probably want to give the `normalem` package option to `ulem` then

Comment: @DaiBowen It indeed solved my problem ! Thank you both of you.